# GNOME Terminal - identical I/O among multiple tabs

Tags: gnome-terminal, tabs

So I've got this problem (?) - whenever I open multiple tabs whithin the GNOME Terminal window I get the very same view on every each of them (e.g. I open man pages on the 1st one - I've got man pages on the 2nd tab as well). Multiple windows work fine.

I've already tried to reinstall the latest version of the package but it didn't help.

Any ideas? In advance, thank you for answers. :) Cheers!

PS: I am using Ubuntu 18.04.02

Comment: Can you also _use_ the man viewer properly in the other tab? Does perhaps highlighting with the mouse change the contents to the expected one?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it turned out that I'm an idiot. :D Instead of switching tabs ('ctrl' + 'Pg Up/Dn) I was moving their position ('shift' + 'ctrl' + 'Pg Up/Dn') and since they were both named the same I couldn't tell the difference.. Thank you for your reply!